# How to extract strings from a text in shell

Tags: shell, sh

I have a file name

```
"PHOTOS_TIMESTAMP_5373382"
```

I want to extract from this filename `"PHOTOS_5373382"` and add `"ABC"` i.e. finally want it to look like

`"abc_PHOTOS_5373382"` in shell script.

Comment: `mv PHOTOS_TIMESTAMP_5373382 abc_PHOTOS_5373382`? Or are you trying to say that "TIMESTAMP" and "ABC" are place-holders for generic text?

Comment: Try looking into the `cut` command

Comment: `sed` is your friend

Answer (score 4):

`echo "PHOTOS_TIMESTAMP_5373382" | awk -F"_" '{print "ABC_"$1"_"$3}'`

`echo` will provide input for `awk` command.

`awk` command does the data tokenization on character `'_'` of input using the option `-F`.

Individual token (starting from 1) can be accessed using `$n`, where `n` is the token number.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the following sequence of commands directly on your shell, preferably `bash` shell (or) as a complete script which takes a single argument the file to be converted

```
#!/bin/bash

myFile="$1"                                            # Input argument (file-name with extension)
filename=$(basename "$myFile")                         # Getting the absolute file-path
extension="${filename##*.}"                            # Extracting the file-name part without extension
filename="${filename%.*}"                              # Extracting the extension part
IFS="_" read -r string1 string2 string3 <<<"$filename" # Extracting the sub-string needed from the original file-name with '_' de-limiter
mv -v "$myFile" ABC_"$string1"_"$string3"."$extension" # Renaming the actual file
```

On running the script as

```
$ ./script.sh PHOTOS_TIMESTAMP_5373382.jpg
`PHOTOS_TIMESTAMP_5373382.jpg' -> `ABC_PHOTOS_5373382.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I like awk

Native shell solution

```
k="PHOTOS_TIMESTAMP_5373382"
IFS="_" read -a arr <<< "$k"
echo abc_${arr[0]}_${arr[2]}
```

Sed solution

```
echo "abc_$k" | sed -e 's/TIMESTAMP_//g'
abc_PHOTOS_5373382
```